# Where should Apache Livy be installed in cluster

Tags: apache-spark, livy

We want to use apache Livy so that we can invoke spark job from restapi. So do we need to install Livy server on name node or edge node. What is the best practice.

Our spark fat jar will reside in NFS path.

Answer (score 1):

Livy can be installed anywhere.You just need to configure it correctly to use the resource manager.It would be easier to configure if you install in Edge node from where you run the spark-submit.